# Browser compatibility for button

Tags: html

I have the following html:

```html
<div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information
</div>
<a href="$codecontact">Contact  $adcontact_name</a>
<a href="tel:$adcontactphone">
  <div class="phone">$adcontactphone
  </div>
</a>
<div class="location">
  <Location: </label> London, UK</div>
```

This makes a button link to dialing screen on mobile, with the number displayed on screen.

It works fine in Android, on Chrome/ Firefox, but as soon as I try it on an Apple phone on Safari, instead of just linking to dialing screen with the number displayed, it asks if I want to dial this:

```
<br><label>,hone<label>07945xxxx
```

When I press yes, it says it can't dial:

```
<br><label>,hone<label>07945xxxx
```

For obvious reasons in that it can't dial a code.

This must be a Safari iPhone/Mac issue, and what on earth does 'hone' mean anyway?

So I tried this html after the  tag in my header.php, to make my site browser compatible.

```
<script 
src="css_browser_selector.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This didn't work for the phone issue (there are others but let's stick to this for now.)

So how do I get apple iPhone, using Safari browser, to perform the same simple task as Firefox, Chrome, Android etc.

Perhaps there is a way to hide

```
<br><label.....
```

Like:

```
.div class ["<BR><label..."] 
{display: none}
```

? It's behaving like published text so treat it as such?

I came across this but not sure what to do with it or if it is the right code? I'm getting the same issue with Google maps

```
"<"followedby"!"<br/><label>Phone: 
</label>""followedby">"
"<"followedby"!"<br/>. 
<label>Location: 
</label>""followedby">"
```

But

```
 $adcontactphone
```

Represents generic phone as well as specific phone number -including label tags

Comment: The code you've shown does not even do what you say it does unless you're using some other library you've not referenced here, since it's invalid HTML.

Comment: @Dantessss Please do not edit code in a user's question, since the answer may very well be that their code is invalid.

Comment: Some of it comes from a plugin, other parts are generated by me and give labels a class etc. If you have Android Chrome /Firefox you can view it working here:https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/14/nicos-cleaning-service/london/uk/business-advert/

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we expect questions to be self-contained as much as possible and at least reference what libraries, etc. are being used. We shouldn't need a link to your site to give an answer. See [ask].

Comment: Ok. Any ideas though?

Comment: If your snippet is as coded in your app, this might just be how Safari is trying to reconcile this bit of invalid markup `<Location: </label>`

Comment: It looks like you're using php because of the $ prefix in front of your ```$adcontactphone``` variable. If it is a variable then you're definitely putting html tags inside that ```adcontactphone``` variable, which is being inserted in the anchor's href attribute.

Comment: Yes, but not with Chrome or Firefox and why not? Because if it works in chrome, the question is just browser compatibility. Thanks

Comment: @Scrimothy. I think you're right, but it works in Chrome...

Comment: Invalid markup is _always_ an unknown in what you'll get across browsers. They all have different ways of trying to intelligently assume what you meant. Some issues are easier than others for all browsers to make the same assumptions. Start by fixing your markup and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: But if Chrome can correctly assume, there must be a way of telling Safari to correctly assume?

Comment: I take it that you are using php then; Somewhere in your script you are assigning a string value to ```$adcontactphone``` that looks like this: ```<br/><label>Phone:</label> 7576XXXXXX``` ... obviously you just want the href attribute to look like ```href="tel:7576XXXXXX"```, so move the html tags to the button and just put the phone number by itself in the variable. You probably still have other problems to solve after fixing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [link](https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/14/nicos-cleaning-service/london/uk/business-advert/) provided in the comments I can deduce that `$adcontactphone` is being assigned the following value:
`<br/><label>Phone:</label> 7576XXXXXX`

You can see that string contains valid html tags, but then you are using `$adcontactphone` inside an `href` attribute:

```php
<a href="tel:$adcontactphone">
    ...
</a>
```

This results in the following html after interpolating the variable:

```html
<a href="tel:<br/><label>Phone:</label> 7576XXXXXX">
    ...
</a>
```

Many browsers will not consider this as a usable value for href. Some browsers may be made to filter out tags inside the attribute and others may not. This is not a browser compatibility issue because each browser is free to handle this invalid attribute in its own way.

If you fix `$adcontactphone` to contain just the phone number you will find that the link will start working in most browsers. The result you are aiming for would be this:

```html
<a href="tel:7576XXXXXX">
    ...
</a>
```

There are also other invalid html problems that should be fixed to be sure that this section of your page is consistent across all browsers. For example:

```html
<div class="location">
    <Location: </label> London, UK</div>
```

You have an unmatched `<` here, also `Location` is not a supported html tag so some browsers may not like that.

Maybe it should look like this?

```html
<div class="location">
    <label>Location:</label> London, UK
</div>
```

Comment: It's probably the right answer. Thanks. It will just be difficult to untie $adcontactphone